# while performance testing application using jmeter with prometheous how to monitor cloud servers?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, google-cloud-monitoring

How to monitor web-based application for performance testing using JMeter and servers are cloud servers (AWS) doesn't have IP Address, Username and password? How to monitor AWS servers need to check CPU, MEMORY, NETWORK and DISK? How to find out the root cause analysis suggest me free tools as an alternative to App Dynamics?

can anyone please help me

Comment: The question is a little bit unclear to me. When you say cloud servers do not have an IP address (I am leaving out the username and password for now) what do you mean? **All** VM instances in GCP have **internal IP addresses** that are allocated to them from a pool of IP ranges set at the subnet level. Depending on the setup and config, VM may also have ephemeral, external IP addresses. So I do not understand the context here and you need to better detail your envs, with more relevant info, tests, expected results etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [Prometheus Listener for JMeter](https://github.com/kolesnikovm/jmeter-prometheus-listener) plugin - you won't be able to get any information regarding system(s) under test using this plugin, it sends to Prometheus only [JMeter-related metrics](https://github.com/kolesnikovm/jmeter-prometheus-listener#metrics) mainly for [real-time collecting and displaying JMeter test results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html), nothing more.

You need to reach out to your application developers/devops and ask them to integrate JMeter with Prometheus.

It's possible to collect and send [custom metrics](https://github.com/kolesnikovm/jmeter-prometheus-listener#custom-metrics) but JMeter needs to get them from the servers you're testing somewhere somehow.

So I would rather consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) or [JMeter SSHMon Plugin](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon) instead.